# Проблема при установке VirtualBox

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion, windows-10

Работаю в `Windows 10`, необходимо установить `Genymotion`.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при завершении установки происходит ошибка, со следующим содержанием

> "Во время установки,произошла неисправимая ошибка".

Уже несколько дней бьюсь над проблемой. Гугление ничего не дало. Ошибка происходит при установке любой версии `VirtualBox`.

Кто сталкивался с подобным,может подскажете как исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что уже установлено и с чем происходит ошибка? Что если удалить обе программы и поставить в другом порядке?

Comment: Виртуалбокс вроде пишет, что совместимость с Win 10 плохая/отсутствует. Откатывайтесь назад, на 7/8

Comment: @Qwertiy,пробовал ставить и в разном порядке,но толку от этого ноль

Comment: @metalurgus,вышла версия 5.0.4,которая уже как бы совместима

Comment: решил проблему?